# VB.net datasource filter

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, combobox, onselect

I have a datagridview with datasource an Acces table. 
The datagridview is filled and perfect but now I want to create an extra Combobox with a filter possibility.

This is in my load function of the page:

```
Private Sub ArchiefFacturatie_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'CharelIjsDataSet.tblFactuur' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.

    Me.TblFactuurTableAdapter.Fill(Me.CharelIjsDataSet.tblFactuur)

'Filling comboxbox part skipped

End Sub
```

At this moment the combobox is filled an the datagridview also. 
Now I created an on selectChange action on the combobox.

I had no idea how to tackle this but I've tried it:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectionChangeCommitted
    'Ophalen id artikel
    Dim klantid As Integer
    klantid = ComboBox1.SelectedValue

    Dim klantidstr As String
    klantidstr = klantid.ToString

    'Via query overige gegevens ophalen
    ' OLEDB select query 
    Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection
    Dim DBpath As String = "C:\Facturatie\CharelIjs.accdb"
    Dim sConnectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & DBpath & ";Persist Security Info=True"
    myConnection = New OleDbConnection(sConnectionString)
    myConnection.Open()
    Dim SQLstr As String
    SQLstr = "SELECT * FROM tblKlant  WHERE KlantID = @id"
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(SQLstr, myConnection)
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim ds As New DataSet()

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", OleDbType.VarChar)
    cmd.Parameters(0).Value = klantid

    Try
        da.Fill(ds, "tblKlant")
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Can't load Web page" & vbCrLf & ex.Message)
        Return
    End Try

    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("tblKlant")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of all that code in `SelectionChangeCommitted` event handler for a start.  You have a typed `DataSet` so use it.  Open the DataSet designer by double-clicking the DataSet in the Solution Explorer.  You should have a `TblKlantTableAdapter` adapter.  Right-click it and add a new query.  Add your filtered query and name the methods `FillByKlantID` and `GetDataByKlantID`.

Back in your form designer, add an instance of your table adapter and a BindingSource.  Bind the `BindingSource` to tblKlant in your `DataSet` and bind your grid to the `BindingSource`.  Now, when the user makes a selection, you first clear the table in the `DataSet`, then you get the ID from the `ComboBox` and pass it to a call to that `FillByKlantID` method.  That will get the filtered data from the database and populate the `DataTable`.  Because the `DataTable` is bound to the `BindingSource` and that's bound to the grid, the data will be displayed.

Comment: Sounds good, do you have a tutorial or an example of this method?